# Как перенести значения с одного поля в другое PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет

У меня есть таблица, в которой есть имя (name), дата создания (created_at), ид изображения (image_id). Там порядка 400 записей, у большинства имена дублируются (т.е мы на деле мы имеем около 200 записей, у которых имена встречаются по 2 раза), но у одного из дублей записи имеется ид изображения, а у другого нет. Как мне сделать перенос image_id с одного дубля на другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with image_ids as (
  select name, image_id from my_table where image_id is not null
)
update
  set image_id = image_ids.image_id
from
 my_table inner join image_ids using(name)
where
 my_table.image_id is null
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Немного модифицировал запрос до:
WITH image_ids AS (
    SELECT name, image_id
    FROM my_table WHERE image_id IS NOT null
)
UPDATEmy_table
    SET image_id = (
        SELECT image_id
        FROM image_ids
        WHERE image_ids.name=my_table.name
        )
WHERE image_id IS null;